# Copy file from Windows to Linux via scp (from Linux)

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, scp

I'm currently using `scp` to copy files between Linux systems.

```
scp username@hostname:/tmp/test.file .
```

Which copies my file from the remote server to the local machine.

What I would like to do is use the same `scp` command from my local Linux machine but copy a file from a Windows destination instead. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Read this for winscp scripting: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline

Comment: PSCP example: http://superuser.com/questions/532919/how-to-use-pscp-to-copy-file-from-unix-machine-to-windows-machine-where-target-p

Comment: Patrick i can only connect to windows from linux machine (Shared folder) i cannot install anything on that machine

Comment: Given the number of false starts in the comments and answer below, please learn to write a more complete specification of your Q the first time ;-) . Don't assume that readers understand your constraints up front. i.e. 
"i cannot install anything on that machine". (even this ambiguous, do you mean your linux machine or the windows machine (yes we know now, windows) , Be clear, please). And Good luck resolving your problem.

Comment: Thank shelter i understand i will improve my questions

Answer (score 6):

You can use commands available with `winscp` to do this on the command line.

[winscp command line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline)

This syntax is pretty close to the Linux `scp` command - but with Window-ish flags.

You can find the `winscp.exe` executable at this path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe
```

**EDIT 01:**

And if you want to use `scp` on the Linux machine to copy from the Windows machine, you will need to run a `ssh` server on the Windows box.

[FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/)

[OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server)

**EDIT 02**:

If you cannot install a `ssh` server on the Windows machine, you can mount an exported directory from Windows onto Linux using the `samba fs mount`.

[samba fs mount](http://www.linuxnix.com/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux/)

Comment: Ok i understand so what i need to install on windows to do that

Comment: You need to run a ssh server on the Windows box. I edited the answer to add this.

Comment: Edited answer for another option using `samba fs mount`.

Comment: Thanks much ziffusion for more options am trying

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution

Downloaded pscp and used commandline option and then scheduled a job

```
c:\pscp.exe -q -batch -l mramkumar -pw xxxxx "c:\alm_testlink.png" mgr.sjc:/home/mramkumar
```

Created a as bat file and scheduled as a job,
This will keep pushing all the files in the folder to my linux server without prompting any password

Comment: First need to Generate a ssh key for windows, using PuttyGen and put into remote Linux authorized_keys. Then `pscp.exe -i .\ssh\id_rsa  .\Temp.py username@10.138.0.6:/home/username/`